# Probability: How to find what proportion is between the 2 values

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that head sizes (circumference) of new recruits in the Canadian armed forces can be
approximated by a normal distribution with a mean of 22.8 inches and a standard deviation
of 1.1 inches.

What proportion of recruits have head sizes between 22 and 23 inches?

What rule do I use for this? Do I use chebyshev's rule for this where 1-1/k?

If anyone can help me out. It would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote **normally distributed**.

$23$ inches is $\dfrac{23-22.8}{1.1}$ standard deviations above the mean.  What proportion of a **normally distributed** population is less than that many standard deviations above the mean?  That's something you usually find using a table or software.

(In this cases it's the proportion that's less than $23$ inches **minus** the proportion that's less than $22$ inches.  Proportions less than a specified number of standard deviations above the mean is what the most usualy sort of table gives.)